# Scroll overflow div to an element and make it stop on the base of the div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to scroll an overflow div until I reach a specific element #id.
My issue is:
I don't want this element to "scrollTop". I want to stop the scroll when the element is visible on the div bottom. Like this:

[image]

All I got was something to scrollTop...

```
function scrollItem(itemID) {
    var container = $('#overflowDIV'),
        scrollTo = $(itemID);

    container.animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try subtracting the inner height of the container. Here is untested code.

```
function scrollItem(itemID) {
  var container = $('#overflowDIV'),
    scrollTo = $(itemID);

  container.animate({
    scrollTop: 
      scrollTo.offset().top - 
      container.offset().top + 
      container.scrollTop() -
      container.innerHeight()
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!
I just increased the LI height container.innerHeight() + 30 and worked beautifully!

Comment: Good call on the item's height. If you don't want to hard code the 30, you could try getting it as well:  container.innerHeight() + scrollTo.height()